# Web crawler does not open all links in a page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, urllib

I'am trying to build a web crawler using beautifulsoup and urllib. The crawler is working, but it does not open all the pages in a site. It opens the first link and goes to that link, opens the first link of that page and so on.
Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import json, sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

url = input('enter url ')
d = {}
d_2 = {}
l = []
url_base = url
count = 0

def f(url):
    global count
    global url_base
    if count <= 100:
        print("count: " + str(count))
        print('now looking into: '+url+'\n')
        count += 1
        l.append(url)
        html = urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        d[count] = soup
        tags = soup('a')

        for tag in tags:
            meow = tag.get('href',None)

            if (urljoin(url, meow) in l):
                print("Skipping this one: " + urljoin(url,meow))
            elif "mailto" in urljoin(url,meow):
                print("Skipping this one with a mailer")    
            elif meow == None:
                print("skipping 'None'")

            elif meow.startswith('http') == False:
                f(urljoin(url, meow))    
            else:
                f(meow)
    else:
        return


f(url)
print('\n\n\n\n\n')
print('Scrapping Completed')
print('\n\n\n\n\n')
```

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: if you don't use any rule to control it then it will never stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this behavior is due to when the code recursively calls your function. As soon as the code finds a valid link, the function `f` gets called again preventing the rest of the for loop from running until it returns.

What you're doing is a depth first search, but the internet is very deep. You want to do a breadth first search instead.

Probably the easiest way to modify your code to do that is to have a global list of links to follow. Have the for loop append all the scraped links to the end of this list and then outside of the for loop, remove the first element of the list and follow that link.

You may have to change your logic slightly for your max count.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. That worked perfectly. But, can i specify a depth count? like, i want to do five levels of breath first search?

Comment: Sure. Add a parameter to the function that keeps track of the depth level: def f(url, depth) -- Then when you recursively call it, call it with (depth + 1). Don't forget to add a check at the beginning that returns immediately if it's above your desired depth.

Answer (score 0):

If `count` reaches 100, no further links will be opened. Therefore I think you should decrease `count` by one after leaving the for loop. If you do this, `count` would be something like the current link depth (and 100 would be the maximum link depth).

If the variable `count` should refer to the number of opened links, then you might want to control the link depth in another way.